# Is it possible to use a Go package built from a different version?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm using Go for Google App Engine, which uses an older version of Go.  I want to use a third party package that requires a newer version of Go (goauth). It is possible to use that package in my Google App Engine program?

Goauth uses strings.SplitN, which does not seem to be present in the GAE version of Go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not without hacking the source of oauth to make it compatible, I'm afraid.

Either that, or you can try and contact the author to see if they are willing to publish a version compatible with AppEngine's Go version.

A third option would be to find an older revision of oauth which is compatible with your Go version and just use that one.

Comment: I ended up finding an earlier version that was compatible and just used that one.

Comment: Can you post a link to where you found that version?